# XCreateColormap giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, x11, glx

I have no idea what it going on.

I spent around 3 hours trying to fix it, but no luck.
My code is:
`

```
    temp->wA.border_pixel = BlackPixel(temp->d, temp->sID);
    temp->wA.background_pixel = WhitePixel(temp->d, temp->sID);
    temp->wA.override_redirect = true;
    temp->wA.colormap = XCreateColormap(temp->d, RootWindow(temp->d, temp->sID), temp->vI->visual, AllocNone);
    temp->wA.event_mask = ExposureMask;
```

The whole code of the function is this:

```
window *createWindow(int height, int width, const char *name)
{
    window *temp = (window *)malloc(sizeof(window));
    temp->d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    temp->s = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(temp->d);
    temp->sID = DefaultScreen(temp->d);
    int tempattribs[] = {
        GLX_RGBA,
        GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,
        GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 24,
        GLX_STENCIL_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_RED_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 0,
        GLX_SAMPLES, 0,
        None};
    memcpy(temp->attribs, tempattribs, sizeof(tempattribs));
    temp->vI = glXChooseVisual(temp->d, temp->sID, temp->attribs);
    if (temp->vI == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR: GLXCHOOSEVISUAL FAILED!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    temp->wA.border_pixel = BlackPixel(temp->d, temp->sID);
    temp->wA.background_pixel = WhitePixel(temp->d, temp->sID);
    temp->wA.override_redirect = true;
    temp->wA.colormap = XCreateColormap(temp->d, RootWindow(temp->d, temp->sID), temp->vI->visual, AllocNone);
    temp->wA.event_mask = ExposureMask;
    temp->w = XCreateWindow(temp->d, RootWindow(temp->d, temp->sID), 0, 0, height, width, 0, temp->vI->depth, InputOutput, temp->vI->visual, CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWEventMask, &temp->wA);
    temp->c = glXCreateContext(temp->d, temp->vI, NULL, 1);
    glXMakeCurrent(temp->d, temp->w, temp->c);
    return temp;
}
```

In case you are wondering what is going on, I have a struct containing all the elements; the code above initialises the elements.
Here is the struct:

```
    typedef struct window
    {
        Window w;
        Display *d;
        Screen *s;
        XEvent e;
        int sID;
        bool running;
        XVisualInfo *vI;
        GLXContext c;
        XSetWindowAttributes wA;
        int attribs[];
    } window;
```

`

I ran a debugger on it and got this result:

```
typ
Thread 1 "main" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000007ff7e10754 in _XcmsAddCmapRec () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6e here
```

Comment: You do realize, that you don't need a colormap for a direct color visual which is most certainly what you want to use with OpenGL.

Comment: I'm using a tutorial on GLX and X11 to make an OpenGL context, and all of them tell me to make a colormap.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it finished, by creating another colormap and assigning the original colormap to the new one.